# Django/Json: Can i easily change how django serializes objects?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have Serialized and dumped my objects like this:

```
data = serializers.serialize("python", MyObject.objects.all())
    dic = { 'Studium' : data} 
    return JsonResponse(dic, safe=False)
```

The response I get:

```
{"Studium": [{"model": "djangoApp.studium", "pk": 538, "fields": {"studiumkode": "ABIOK", "studium": "ABIOK (anestesi/barnevern/intensiv/operasjon/kreftsykepleie"}}]}
```

The response I want:

```
{"Studium": {"studiumkode": "ABIOK", "studium": "ABIOK (anestesi/barnevern/intensiv/operasjon/kreftsykepleie"}}
```

Comment: Does `dic = { 'Studium': data[0]['fields'] }` work?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, it does! But what if I want more than one object?

Comment: `dic = { 'Studium': [d['fields'] for d in data] }`

Comment: TY! That worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer commented by @jordanm:

```
dic = { 'Studium': data[0]['fields'] }
```

returns:

```
{"Studium": {"studiumkode": "ABIOK", "studium": "ABIOK (anestesi/barnevern/intensiv/operasjon/kreftsykepleie"}}
```

Solution for list of objects

```
dic = { 'Studium': [d['fields'] for d in data] }
```